# Automatically fix luminosity differences between frames

Tags: time-lapse, premiere

I created timelapse sequence in Adobe Premiere Pro. Unfortunately, source images are not consistent in luminosity (shutter speed slightly differs), which results in "flickering" of the image.

Does Premiere have an option to automatically "fix" this, by averaging luminosity between frames?

Comment: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10505/premiere-and-image-sequence-correction-problem

Comment: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/3406/correcting-exposure-flickering-in-time-lapse-footage-in-after-effects

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39085/how-to-deal-with-large-exposure-shifts-during-time-lapse